# How to pass a ajax variable value to php page?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable value using ajax. When I run the file alert box showing the correct value "hi" but I got an error on test.php

> Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\wamp64\www\abrar\superadmin\test.php on line 19

my code is

**superadminviewbtn.php**

HTML

```
<script>
var message = "Hi";
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  method: "post",
  data: {
    "message": message
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(message);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Not OKay');
  }
});
</script>
```

**test.php**

PHP

```
<?php
$msg = $_POST['message'];
echo $msg;
?>
```

but it's showing an error in `test.php`

[image: error screen shot]

Comment: You appear to be opening `test.php` directly in your browser. You will only see the response from the AJAX POST request within the `success` handler

Comment: Try using "postman" to confirm your PHP is working as intended. With postman you can craft a POST request with the JSON body containing your message. Then you can focus on JavaScript separately.

Comment: `var_dump` the `$_POST` variable and see what data you are getting. Also, check your web server/localhost settings if something is blocking your POST requests.

Comment: The AJAX request, and the request made when you load test.php directly via your browser address bar, are two separate requests, that have nothing to do with each other. You only send the parameter with the AJAX request, so it will only be available in that running _instance_ of your script triggered by this request. If you want data you send via AJAX available on other pages or in other requests later, then you will have to store it into a session or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your `success: function`:

```
success: function(data) {
  /* data is the return string form the PHP script! */
  alert("PHP response is: "+ data);
  /* message is the input you send to the PHP script! */
  // alert(message); -> this is incorrect
}
```

Please try again after this change, by running the parent script (`superadminviewbtn.php`). Did it work?